# Show preview of a file in html in angular 5

Tags: html, angular, file

I need to preview files of the format pdf or doc. I looked for solutions which included using  with the googledocsviewer but the file that I want to preview is present right in the application as a File object. Itried using the  with the fileReader.readasDataUrl function and was able to preview txt and image format files, but I need to work with the other formats too.I came across a npm package called file preview https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepreview but I could not understand how to use it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: pdf is easy - doc is the tricky part. If `.doc` is crucial, consider saving it as a temp file, and then link that file with google docs. if mobile support is a top priority however, i'd go with converting it to an Image using Ghostscript\Aspose\OpenOffice\PdfCreator or such and embed that instead.

Comment: So there is no other solution than to link the document with google docs?

Comment: or office live, yes, (`http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=`) I am not aware of any client-side way to show a doc file, not sure one exists that is stable enough for production. again, i'd go with converting it to HTML / image / PDF and display that instead.